# C Program - How to read a file and store its texts in a variable?

Tags: c

Please bear with me since I'm still new in programming. I need to read `/proc/cpuinfo` to determine a router's model, the file looks like this:

```
system type             : bcm63xx/HW553 (0x6358/0xA1)
machine                 : Unknown
processor               : 0
cpu model               : Broadcom BMIPS4350 V1.0
BogoMIPS                : 299.26
wait instruction        : yes
microsecond timers      : yes
tlb_entries             : 32
extra interrupt vector  : yes
hardware watchpoint     : no
isa                     : mips1 mips2 mips32r1
ASEs implemented        :
shadow register sets    : 1
kscratch registers      : 0
core                    : 0
VCED exceptions         : not available
VCEI exceptions         : not available
```

What I need to store in a variable is this part `bcm63xx/HW553 (0x6358/0xA1)`. It is the model number and it changes constantly, here's what I have tried so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( void )
{
  char filename[] = "/proc/cpuinfo";
  FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );

  if (file != NULL) {
    char line [1000];
    while(fgets(line,sizeof line,file)!= NULL) /* read a line from a file */ {
      fprintf(stdout,"%s",line); //print the file contents on stdout.
    }

    fclose(file);
  }
  else {
    perror(filename); //print the error message on stderr.
  }

  return 0;
}
```

But that script only prints the file, I don't know how to store the router's model in a variable, how should I do it?

PS:
After storing the router's model in a variable I need to compare it whether it matches the pre-defined variable or not.

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to make it a function, my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* model() {
    char filename[] = "/proc/cpuinfo";
    char* key = "system type";
    char* value;
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file != NULL) {
        char line[1000];
        char* router_model = NULL;

        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) /* read a line from a file */ {
            fprintf(stdout, "%s", line); //print the file contents on stdout.
            if (strncmp(line, key, strlen(key)) == 0) {
                char* value = strchr(line, ':');
                value += 2;
                router_model = strdup(value);
                break;   // once the key has been found we can stop reading
            }
        }
        fclose(file);

        if (router_model != NULL) {
            printf("The model is %s\n", router_model);    // print router model
        }
        else {
            printf("No %s entry in %s\n", key, filename); // key not found, print some error message
        }
        free(router_model);
    }
    else {
        perror(filename); //print the error message on stderr.
    }
    return router_model;

}
int main(void)
{
    char* ret;
    ret = model();
    printf("Model: %s\n", ret);
    return 0;
}
```

But I get an error:

```
test.c: In function ‘model’:
test.c:37:9: error: ‘router_model’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  return router_model;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
test.c:37:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

How do I fix it ?

Comment: 1. read line by line.2. use strtok to make it key value pair.3. find required value by comparison of key with predefined key.

Comment: In the third version of your post, I see `router_model` declared, but you also include the error text about this, which was not in the first version of your post.  Could you confirm that the error message still occurs, with the `router_model` declaration right after that `line` declaration?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your line, check that it starts with the key string you're looking for.

```
char* key = "system type";
...
if (strncmp(line, key, strlen(key)) == 0) {
  /* this is the line you want */
}
```

Once you've identified the line, find the first colon.

```
char* value = strchr(line, ':');
```

Now you have the value, although it will include the leading colon and space, so you can iterate past those.

```
value += 2;
```

And then you should be able to use this result. Note that I have not allocated any new space. If you want to save this value somewhere, then you'll need to copy the string. The easiest way to do this is to *duplicate* it.

```
char* router_model = strdup(value);
```

You will have to `free()` this string once you are finished with it.

Comment: Can you take a look at my post again ? I still can't get it sorted out

Comment: @Squidward You need to set `router_model` inside the conditional, right after you get `value` to what you want. That implies that `router_model` has to be declared as a variable outside of the loop. (And be sure to put `printf()` statements after each line while you debug this!)

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char filename[] = "/proc/cpuinfo";
  char* key = "system type";
  char* value;
  FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

  if (file != NULL) {
    char line[1000];
    char* router_model = NULL;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) /* read a line from a file */ {
      fprintf(stdout, "%s", line); //print the file contents on stdout.
      if (strncmp(line, key, strlen(key)) == 0) {
        char* value = strchr(line, ':');
        value += 2;
        router_model = strdup(value);
        break;   // once the key has been found wen can stop reading
      }
    }
    fclose(file);

    if (router_model != NULL)
       printf("The model is %s\n", router_model);    // print router model
    else
       printf("No %s entry in %s\n", key, filename); // key not found, print some error message

    free(router_model);
  }
  else {
    perror(filename); //print the error message on stderr.
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is your code with slight modifications and some comments.

Note that there is still room for improvement.

Comment: I'm trying to store it as a function but I get an error, can you take a look at my post agan please ?

Comment: The suggestions are good.  Asking him to look again is not the right way to go.  You should look again at his code.  Also, there is no storage as a function.  There is storage as a variable, as you correctly worded it in your post.  Do that.

Answer (score 0):

using strtok and strip, trim for achieve key value pair of above program.so that easy compare of key and clear logic of problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *strip(char *str){
        if(str == NULL){
                return str;
        }
        int j = 0;
        while(str[0] != '\0' && isspace(str[0])){
                j=0;
                while(str[j] != '\0'){
                        str[j] = str[j+1];
                        j++;
                }
        }
        return str;
}

char *trim(char *str){
        if(str == NULL){
                return str;
        }
        int len = strlen(str)-1;
        while(isspace(str[len])){
                str[len]='\0';
                len--;
        }
        return str;
}
int process_line(char *str, char *res_key, char *res_value){
        char *key, *value;
        key = strtok(str, ":");
        value = strtok(NULL, ":");
        if( key && value){
                key = strip(key);
                key = trim(key);
                value = strip(value);
                value = trim(value);
                //printf("%s:%s\n", key, value);
                strcpy(res_key, key);
                strcpy(res_value, value);
        }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char filename[] = "/proc/cpuinfo";
        char* key = "system type";
        char* value;
        FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
        if (file != NULL) {
                char line[2048]={0x00};
                char temp_key[1024]={0x00};
                char temp_value[1024]={0x00};
                while (fscanf(file, " %[^\n]s", line) != EOF) /* read a line from a file */ {
                        process_line(line, temp_key, temp_value);
                        if(strcmp(temp_key, key) == 0){
                                break;
                        }
                        memset(line, 0x00, sizeof(line));
                        memset(temp_key, 0x00, sizeof(temp_key));
                        memset(temp_value, 0x00, sizeof(temp_value));
                }
                fclose(file);
                printf("model:%s\n", temp_value);
        }
        else {
                perror(filename); 
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I think this should solve your problem